# No effect when use the command setlist with enumitem and outlines packages

Tags: numbering, lists, enumitem

I want to change the default labels of `outlines` package by using `enumitem` package, but the `\setlist` command does not work at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\alph*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{outline}
\1 x
\2 xx
\3 xxx
\4 xxxx
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default list environment used by [`outlines`](http://ctan.org/pkg/outlines) is `itemize`. If you want to use an `enumerate`, you have to adjust what the `outline` environment uses. This is done by redefining `\ol@type`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=A\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=B(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=C\roman*.}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=D\Alph*.}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ol@type}{enumerate}% Use enumerate instead of itemize
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{outline}
  \1 x
  \2 xx
  \3 xxx
  \4 xxxx
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer inspires me. We can also get the same effect by changing  `\begin{outline}` to `\begin{outline}[enumerate]`.